# How to Parse json with many slashes

Tags: android, json, parsing

The json response of my web service similar to this :

```
"{\u000d\u000a  \"tblworksheets\": [\u000d\u000a    {\u000d\u000a      \"action\": \"<a style=\\\"cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline\\\" runat=\\\"server\\\"  onclick=\\\"getWorksheet(640)\\\">Edit<\/a>\",\u000
```

Kindly help me how to deal with this kind of a structure.

Comment: Why aren't you just using JSONObject or similar parser that will do this for you?

Comment: Tell your webservice to stop spitting out "formatted" json. the \u000d\u000a` is just a bunch of encoded `\r\n` chars. That being said, you should be able to just load it into your json parser as-is. None of those backslashes is optional and MUST be present for it to stay valid json.

Comment: This response is coming from the server side. This kind of response is called what ? How to parse this in android? can you explain a bit more in detail @marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use replace function to remove all slashes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ ?

It should be able to create your JSON object using the default constructor

Comment: what is the use of gson